# MS Access date range parameters

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have some agents data contains leave Start date and leave end date.If I gave 9th july as input and my leave Start date is 9th july and End date is 18th July.I need to get all the agents who took leave on 9th july

Comment: I don't think there is enough info to answer. _"If I gave 9th july"_ Where does this input come from? _"I need to get all the data from 9th july."_ What counts? Data that starts on or after 9th July? Data that ends on or after 9th July? Both? Data that starts and ends within the 9th of July, not before/after on either side?

Comment: Hey can't we give a date as input without getting that from query and run the query based on the date given ?

Comment: Yes, if that's what you want to do. You should include info on what you want to do in your question, so people have something substantial to answer.

Comment: Okay I have some agents data contains leave Start date and leave end date.If I gave 9th july as input and my leave Start date is 9th july and End date is 18th July.I need to get all the agents who took leave on 9th july

Comment: Thanks, but please edit any such info into your question, as it should be self-contained without having to refer to comments. So June7 is on the right track, but the literal date needs to be replaced with the placeholder for your parameter. So, next you need to tell us how your input parameter is set up, or whether you even have one yet.

Comment: My input parameter should look both leave start date and leave end date.I don't have any column in my table as input parameter

Comment: Review http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming year is part of the date, options:

1. `#7/9/2017# = [StartDate]`
2. `#7/9/2017# = [EndDate]`
3. `#7/9/2017# BETWEEN [StartDate] AND [EndDate]`

Comment: Hi June7 .Here in the query how I need to write. ?    #7/9/2017# BETWEEN [StartDate] AND [EndDate].Here in place of #7/9/2017# what date function I have to take .

Comment: I think this will quickly fall apart if the OP's regional date format is different from yours. **edit**: no, Access always expects US format regardless of regional settings: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html#Format

Comment: @vissubabu "what date function I have to take" - that depends on how you are obtaining the 9 July 2017 as the particular date you are looking at.  (Is it coming from another query?  Is it today's date?  Is it entered by the user on some form?  Etc, etc.)  Without knowing that, it is going to be hard to suggest how you include the value within the query.